# AppBar transition in Material-UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, transition, material-ui, jss

Is it possible to add transition to an AppBar element in Material-UI?
It seems like that the class properties get done properly, but still, no animation is made. What am I doing wrong?

Look at the code here: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wwrvwvyqy5)

In my local project, I provide MuiThemeProvider, however, the effect remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if you change the `appBar` style to the following:

```
  appBar: {
    height: theme.spacing.unit * 8,
    "-moz-transition": "height 4s linear",
    "-webkit-transition": "height 4s linear",
    transition: "height 4s linear",
    "&:hover": {
      height: theme.spacing.unit * 16
    }
  }
```

- Change the transition values from arrays to strings.
- Define a default height, so the transition knows the height to transition to/from.

Comment: It worked! I can't remember where I read that values with arrays are okay... But anyway, thanks a lot man!

Comment: Maybe arrays are supported, but I couldn't get it to work in sandbox until including that change.  Glad to help!